# Difference between L* and Σ*

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, formal-languages

Can someone please explain the exact difference between `Σ*` and `L*` , where
`L` is a language and `Σ` is alphabet of the language `L` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Σ is a set of characters.

L is a set of strings.

It ultimately depends on how L is defined. If L = {w | w in Σ} then all of L's words (strings) are single characters from Σ, and L* ≡ Σ*. However, if L is defined differently (example below) L* ≠ Σ*.

Preliminary note: you may have also seen ε represent empty strings, rather than λ. The symbols are interchangeable.

q.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

> ```
> If V is a set of strings then V* is defined as the smallest superset of
> V that contains λ (the empty string) and is closed under the string
> concatenation operation.
>
> If V is a set of symbols or characters then V* is the set of all strings
> over symbols in V, including the empty string.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Example of Kleene star applied to set of strings:
>     {"ab", "c"}* = {λ, "ab", "c", "abab", "abc", "cab", "cc", "ababab",
>                     "ababc", "abcab", "abcc", "cabab", "cabc", "ccab",
>                     "ccc", ...}.
> ```

Notice that "aa" and "bb" appear nowhere in the produced strings.

Σ* is less restrictive:

> ```
> Example of Kleene star applied to set of characters:
>     {'a', 'b', 'c'}* = {λ, "a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb",
>                        "bc", "ca", "cb", "cc", ...}.
> ```